# ProFont missing font after reboot

Tags: 14.04, fonts, gnome-classic

I have installed [ProFont](http://tobiasjung.name/profont/) and enable it by this command:

```
sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

All works good. But the i reboot i see only this:

[image]

How i can make work my `.pcf` fonts in `Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome Fallback`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
ln -s ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf .
```

then:

```
fc-cache -f -v
```

and after reboot all works as expect.